# Magento 2: $.widget is not a function and cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, magento2.1

I am using Magento 2.1.7 version and am facing js errors in the console which causes many issues like could not open the popup, could not open tabs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd6iL.png)

Comment: Use `jQuery` instead of `$` and for more information see this link [Fixing jQuery – Prototype Script Conflicts](https://caspar.green/jquery-prototype-conflict/)

Comment: @M0ns1f Still am getting same error.

Comment: And this is my code:
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function(j$){
        //j$ = jquery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function(){
                 ****
   });
  });
 </script>

Comment: can you put the code where where the `$.widget` is

Comment: Do I need to change $.widget as $j.widget everywhere? Am I getting wrong?

Comment: yes or just change all the `$` to `jQuery` no need to use `j$ = jquery.noConflict(); `